# Is a system of elementary system of complex symmetric polynomials solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: computational-complexity, symmetric-polynomials

Give a generalized system of the form...

$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$
$$a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3 = x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3$$
$$a_1 a_2 a_3 = x_1 x_2 x_3$$

... solvable in polynomial time?

By generalized I mean having $n$ of the $a_i$ and $x_i$ terms, with all the $a_i$ and $x_i$ being complex numbers.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas .

Comment: No, why should it?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I don’t know why it should. Or shouldn’t. That’s my problem :-) Linear systems are I think? And I’m sure plenty aren’t. So thought I’d ask which it belonged to if known.

Answer (score 0):

It is instant. The collection of $x_i$ is merely a permutation of the $a_j$